# use poll package in umbraco website

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I'M using [umbraco CMS](http://umbraco.com/) and i want to add or make poll in my website..

After searching for package i found this one [POLL PACKAGE FOR UMBRACO 4](http://www.nibble.be/?p=69) which you can get it from umbraco site [here](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/poll) . The problem here is that to use it i should insert the macro by myself(the developer) and give it the poll id(which was created by the client).

i want to make this dynamically maybe by using XSLT but the macro is .net UserControl.

if someone used it before give me some idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an option:

You can create another document type, in the template of which you load the macro. You can populate the macro parameters based on the properties that are selected on the node of the document type you created using the [Advanced macro parameter syntax](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/templates/umbracomacro-element/macro-parameters/advanced-macro-parameter-syntax).

For example, you have a Content picker on the document type and you fill the macro with the id of the node that is chosen. In the master page you would do the following:

```
<umbraco:Macro Alias="Poll" runat="server" PollNodeId="[#nodeId]" />
```